# SQL query select message prints itself

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query: where subject table contains names

```
SELECT 
'title in DB: ' || name
FROM subject;
```

and it prints select statement itself

[image]

It happens with all queries.
How to get read of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a table output of the columns you have selected.  If you just want it to have `Name`
do this:

```
SELECT 
'title in DB: ' || name as Name
FROM subject;
```

This is commonly referred to as aliasing a column name.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna change the header, just use an alias

```
select 'title in DB: '|| name as Title
from subject
```